# Jquery submit login data help

Tags: jquery

I am very new and only just learning Jquery. I am currently submitting data from a form and on success it refreshes the div so that it updates.

I know there is a problem with my data sending Jquery code but I've never had to send data.

Can someone tell me what I should use here:

```
 function secure()
{
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "secure.php",
          async: false,
          data: "username="+$("#username")"password="+$("#password").val(), 
           success: function(msg){
                $("#auth").html(msg);
           }
      });
}
```

Comment: I think that should be `$('#username').val+` Was that a copy/paste error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a `.val()`, a `+`, and a `&`.

```
data: "username="+$("#username").val() + "&password="+$("#password").val(),
```

Or just use the [`serialize()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method.

```
data: $("#username,#password").serialize(),
```

...assuming you have the name attributes set on your form elements.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: Thanks. I love my `<sup>`s. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let jQuery worry about serializing the data. Just pass an object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "secure.php",
    async: false,
    data: {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val()
    }, 
    success: function(msg) {
        $("#auth").html(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Since if I had been thinking, I would have passed an object instead of building a string for my first solution!